# Prototype dataCell for view based tables

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

For my view based tables I get my cells like this:

```
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
NSTableCellView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
```

However there are some settings like "Editable" which I want set to all cells of a specific column. I do not want to clutter my cell configuration code by setting the value every time I retrieve the cell. Instead I would like to do some common configuration from my **awakeFromNib** function and do just common manipulations for every cell of the column. Just like I can do visually in XCode

My first approach was this:

```
NSTableColumn *column = [[self tableColumns] objectAtIndex:0];
NSTextFieldCell *cell = [column dataCell];
[cell setEditable:@YES];
```

However *dataCell* only works for cell based tables. Is there an equivalent to get the prototype cell of a column for view based tables?

Comment: [table viewAtColumn:columnIndex row:rowIndex makeIfNecessary:YES]